# WPF- building a model based testing application

Tags: wpf, testing, wpftoolkit

I want to build a model engine for a model base testing application. I assume there are some refernces that can be helpfull. I would like to use the cool features of WPF. Is there anything like this that exists? or any other helpful recommendation?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "model base testing" is?

Comment: Do you mean testing the model of MVVM or MVC? What does model based testing mean?

Comment: I mean actually a way of building a state machine/ graph /tree etc. I do not want ot test the model of MVVM or MVC but build a model for testing other things. what is the way to build those graphs in WPF is there any builtin infrastructure for doing this in VS 2010, want ot use WPF Wilipedia definition for model based testing Model-based testing is:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-based_testing